# Swift Coredata NSPredicate for child of object type

Tags: swift, core-data

I have a Coredata setup of entities `Parent` and `Child`. `Child` is an abstract entity which `Child A`, `Child B`, and `Child C` all inherit from. Each `Parent` has a single child but there is not relationship of `Child` to `Parent`. I'm trying to query a list of all `Parents` with a `Child B`.

I attempted trying to find an NSPredicate such as `child is type Child B` but couldn't find anything. Is there anyway of going about this?

Comment: CoreData relationships usually have a reverse.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.